# Styling notification: increase font size of notif text / inboxStyle line

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

So I am creating an Android notification and want to increase the size of some part of the notification body (ex. a dollar amount), and have been unable to do so.

I have tried the following:

`dollarAmountSpannable.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(24), 0, dollarAmountString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);`

I have also tried the following with RelativeSizeSpan:

`balanceSpannable.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(3.0f), dollarIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);`

I have tried that as the text of both a bigStyle notification and for the line of an inboxStyle notification as such:

`inboxStyle1.addLine(dollarAmountSpannable);`

`bigStyle1.bigText(dollarAmountSpannable)`;

None of these have altered the text at all - the text in question just looks normal.

**Anyone have any other ideas for increasing the text size with a notification?**

Please let me know. Thanks y'all.